# Database tables not created in ios 7 simulator but working correctly in ios 6 simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, simulator

I have this xcode 5 project which works properly (reads/writes from database) on IOS 6 simulator, but it doesn't work when i switch to IOS 7 simulator. It does create a database but it doesn't contain any table. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Start solving the problem by providing more information. What kind of database. Are there commands to create a table, if so what are they. Did they execute? Do they return an error code, if so what is it?

Comment: I'm using core data that creates sqlite database. There is no specific command to create table because core data model handles it. It doesn't however show any error. 

The thing is I was trying to create an event related project with core data. I wasn't able to do so, because of the same problem: database is created but not tables. Also records were not added. So I chose to alter a project which is already working. And thats how I came across this new problem.

As you might have guessed. I'm new to xcode and objective c

Answer (score 0):

Did you save the NSManagedObjectContext after you made some changes?

```
NSError* error = nil;

if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    //Do some error handling
}
```